# Can't embed image in as3 file while build with ant under linux(debian)

Tags: linux, actionscript-3, ant, embed, mxmlc

I embedded a png in as3, it's all fine on windows, either use FB4.6 or Ant. But while build with Ant under linux(debian), I got this Error. Image path is `/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/q5/dev_Flash/code/Copper/src/assets/c001_up.png`. Project name is `/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/q5/dev_Flash/code/Copper`.

```
[mxmlc] /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/q5/dev_Flash/code/Copper/src/com/copper/ui/skin/DefaultAssets.as(10): col: 3: Error: unable to resolve 'assets/c001_up.png' for transcoding
[mxmlc] 
[mxmlc]         [Embed(source = "assets/c001_up.png")]
[mxmlc]   ^
[mxmlc] 
[mxmlc] /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/q5/dev_Flash/code/Copper/src/com/copper/ui/skin/DefaultAssets.as(10): col: 3: Error: Unable to transcode assets/c001_up.png.
```

as3 file like this

```
package com.copper.ui.skin {


/**
 * 
 * @author marzwu
 *
 */
public class DefaultAssets extends Assets {
    [Embed(source = "assets/c001_up.png")]
    private var Button_Up:Class;
```

My ant file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

Q5客户端构建

```
<!-- 配置属性 -->
<property file="build.properties" />

<property environment="env" />
<property name="FLEX_HOME" value="${env.FLEX_HOME}" />

<taskdef resource="flexTasks.tasks" classpath="${FLEX_HOME}/ant/lib/flexTasks.jar" />

<target name="compile">
    <echo message="${basedir}/../src" />
    <compc output="../bin/copper.swc" debug="false" incremental="true">
        <!-- 指定Comman项目的源码目录 -->
        <source-path path-element="${basedir}/../src" />
        <!-- 指定编译的文件列表 -->
        <include-sources dir="${basedir}/../src">
                <include name="**/*.as" />
        </include-sources>
        <!-- 将Flex SDK 作为外部库进行引用 -->
        <compiler.external-library-path dir="${FLEX_HOME}/frameworks">
            <include name="**/*.swc" />
        </compiler.external-library-path>
        <!-- 添加项目中的SWC包,请注意这里是外部 -->
        <compiler.external-library-path dir="../libs">
            <include name="**/*.swc" />
        </compiler.external-library-path>

        <define name="CONFIG::Debug" value="true" />
        <define name="CONFIG::Release" value="false" />

        <jvmarg value="-Xmx2048m"/>
        <jvmarg value="-Xms512m"/>
        <jvmarg value="-XX:MaxPermSize=512m"/>
    </compc>
    <!-- 删除缓存文件 -->
    <delete>
        <fileset dir="../bin" includes="*.cache" />
    </delete>
    <echo message="complier Flex Library Project finished!" />
</target>

<target name="deploy">
    <antcall target="compile" />
    <!--antcall target="copy_to_bin" /-->
    <echo>前往查看结果：http://10.0.1.69/q5d/</echo>
    <echo message="执行发布" />
</target>
```

I use jenkins to build my as3 project. It's bother me for many day. Appreciate for your helping.

Answer (score 0):

Oops, compiler can't resolve the path, because I did not notice the "u" between "c001_up.png" is an upper case letter. Windows are not sensitive of letter case, but linux are. My fault, thank you for your time.